# Grouping across collections using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have two collections in mongoDB that look like this:

This is the collection "posts"

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f986f218df60a5727000002"),
  "threadId" : "16137442",
  "userId" : "374952",
  "postId" : ...,
   ...
}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
  "threadId" : "5947299",
  "userId" : "374952",
  "postId" : ...,
   ...
}
```

This is the collection "threadtopic"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fb012f48df60a565a000000"),
    "topics" : [
    "5"
],
    "maxProportion" : "0.6852791878172588",
    "threadId" : "5947299"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "topics" : [
    "9"
],
    "maxProportion" : "0.712791878172588",
    "threadId" : "16137442"
}
```

I want to create a collection "usertopics" which looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "userId" : 374952,
    "topics" : [ 5, 9, ... ]
}
```

Basically the collection "usertopics" contains a list of all "topics" for each "userId", based on matching "threadId" (from collections "posts" and "threadtopic") and only considers those threadIds from collection "threadtopic" where "maxProportion" is greater than 0.3.

How do I go about doing this using MapReduce?

Comment: A MapReduce can't be used to make a join in a single operation.

Comment: Ok, what about multiple operations? First making a collection of threadIds for each user and then using that to extract topics from the collection "threadtopic"?